How aeron cluster and aeron archive come together?
I am trying to setup a trading system, where I want to ensure that messages arriving on the leader process (running aeron cluster) is getting replicated using Aeron cluster features. But if I want to record them for replay for a given publishing node in a given cluster node, I can do it with Aeron Archive. But as I understand Aeron archive is not getting replicated. And so I believe it will reside on one side of the datacenter. If my cluster nodes run across datacenters, what will happen if my node failsover to secondary node which is in a different datacenter. Do I lose capability to replay messages which were recorded in the primary data center.
I have implemented Aeron archive and have seen how the record and replay works. I did studies on Aeron cluster as well to understand how it works. But I don't see how they can work together in real production setup.
Edit: The above bold statement may be incorrect. I came across Aeron website stating: Archive recordings can be replicated from a source process to a destination process. This is useful for near real-time backups of data. I am yet to see an example suggesting how this can be done or is it out of the box feature.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

The purpose of Aeron Archive is to record and replay local or remote streams in a peer-to-peer rather than brokers fashion. Aeron Archive has a feature to replicate a stream from one archive to another with an API to invoke this.
The purpose of Aeron Cluster is to operate fault-tolerant services (replicated state machines) which take their inputs from a sequenced log which is replicated using the Raft algorithm for consensus. This sequenced log is stored on all nodes of the cluster in local Aeron Archive instances. These archives also store snapshots of service state for reducing the time to recover a restarted instance without needing to replay the log from the beginning of time. A cluster node has a combination of media driver, consensus module, archive, and service containers that all make up a replicated instance for fault tolerance. Services use their local replica of the archive.
